# Why can I successfully specify heap size that exceeds physical memory size?

Tags: jvm

```
java -Xmx100G -Xms100G Hello
```

My macbook pro only gets 8GB of RAM, why JVM can start with the heap size of 100G?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this can happen is because most operating systems (including OSX) support *virtual memory*. In this case, the process asks the operating system for that much space, and is returned something that appears to have the space available. However, the memory is split into *pages* (which is a way of serving it in chunks) and the operating system only fills those pages with real memory when they're actually used. As the JVM starts to use more and more of those pages, they'll be mapped to physical memory first, and then when the memory can't fit into physical memory, will start to *swap* the memory pages out to disk (until the disk runs out, the process hits its limit, at which point it's killed).

This isn't unique to the JVM; other processes will do the same as well.

Comment: I thought JVM would do something like `heap = malloc(1000GB)` when starting. If a process calls `malloc(1MB)` then this 1MB of memory is occupied and other processes cannot use it. Is that right?

Comment: Original JVMs did do exactly this, but the G1GC works in a slightly different way. However, you can still do malloc(1000Gb) on a C program and have it succeed as well. The virtual memory space is just a number at that point, as pages haven't been used. You can see the use if you look at top, or similar, where it shows you the use of real memory to virtual: `PhysMem: 7643M used (1846M wired), 541M unused. VM: 841G vsize`

Comment: One more question. My mac has 8GB RAM, and my program applied 1000GB RAM using `heap = malloc(1000GB)`. What will happen if I keep filling data into `heap`?

Comment: Same as in Java; the OS will map on demand areas of that virtual memory space into real physical pages; when those pages no longer fit in real memory they'll be swapped out to disk. If your disk fills up then you'll eventually terminate the process with a SIGSEV.